# What happened to iPrintSdk?

Tags: android, bluetooth

Does anyone know what happened to the iPrint SDK project? The website (iprintsdk.com) looks to have expired and is no longer available. This just happened within the past few weeks.

Any other good alternatives to print to Bluetooth from an Android app? We're not using Zebra or Star printers so both of their SDKs are out.

Thanks.